# EF 6 different DbSet name from class it holds

Tags: entity-framework-6

For some reason EF isn't making the record class itself singular. The table name is SAOrder_OrderStatuses. It uses that name for both the DbSet and the class. How can I get the class to be SAOrder_OrderStatus? This is DB first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF tries to guess pluralization but doesnt get it right sometimes. You can change the properties of the tables, fields, stored procs, etc that were imported by using the Properties window.

Just select the entity (not one of the fields) in the model's edmx editor. 
Then you can rename the class by entering a different name in the "Name" property. You can also just click the name in the edmx editor and edit in-place.

You can also rename the Set name that you reference in the DBContext. 
You can change field names by selecting those and using the same properties window.

These custom name changes persist even when you refresh the edmx from the database again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the checkmark from

```
'Pluralize or singularize generated object names' in Entity Data Wizard:
```

[image]